# Recursive best first search and finding the best path

Tags: recursion, lisp, graph-algorithm

In a Recursive Best-First Search, how would I modify it, to be able to track back the route?

Would I need to have a data structure that keeps track of which nodes are unwound after last recursion break?

I already have implemented heuristic and helper functions (graph parser, distance calculations) in LISP and RBFS itself as well. Now, in order to print the most optimal path, I  have a list of all return values (result) from each recursion step.

See [RBFS - Recursive Best-First Search Algorithm (PDF, slide 4)](http://mas.cs.umass.edu/classes/cs683/lectures-2010/Lec6_Search5-F2010.pdf).

My LISP code:

```
(defun rbfs (state cost f-limit goal)
  (let ((node (first state))
        (f (second state)))
    (if (equal node goal)
        (list node cost)
        (let ((successors
               (loop
                   :for city :in (expand node)
                   :collect (list city (max (+ cost (getdistance city node)
                                               (getlineardistance city goal)) f))
                   :into successors
                   :finally (sort successors #'my-comparator)))
              (result (list)))
          (if (< (length successors) 2)
              (list fail inf)
              (loop
                 :for best :=  (first successors)
                 :and alternative :=  (second successors)
                 :if (> (second best) f-limit) :do (list fail (second best))
                 :else :if (not (equal node fail) )
                 :do (list node cost)
                 :collect (rbfs best
                                (+ cost (getdistance (first best) node) )
                                (min f-limit (second alternative) ) goal)))))))
```

Now, the problem with this code is that the recursion never unwidnds. Using (trace rbfs) I get something like 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th call and then it repeats this 5th call all over again.

So the question really is how to break recursion within a loop ;)

Comment: In general, "Questions concerning problems with **code you've written** must describe the specific problem — **and include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself."  Now, I recognize that this isn't necessarily a problem in code that you've written, but if you're asking how to modify the code that you've written, you'll help any potential answerers if you can post your existing implementation of RBFS…

Comment: I added the code now.

Comment: Erm, I'd suggest _formatting_ it.  If you edit it, select the code, and press the `{}` button in the editor, it will be formatted as code (that we can read!). :)  (Looking at the source, I see that it's not formatted in the plain text either.  Copy it from some editor that will preserve the spaces, indentation, etc., select it all and press the `{}` button.)

Comment: (please review and make sure it has your corrections from the deleted answer, kthx)

Comment: I checked it and also added my comments. The idea is that I return: (GOALNODE cost_to_goal ... NODE_2 cost_to_2 NODE_1 cost_to_1 STARTNODE 0)

Answer (score 0):

Can you write your code like this (in common-lisp):

```
(defun rbfs (<your-arguments> lst)
    (let ((city (car lst)))
    (append lst (get-successors city))
    (cond ((null lst) NIL)
          ((not (null (goal-test city))) (<return the path>))
          (t (rbfs <your-arguments> (sort (cdr lst)))))))

(defun get-successors (city)
    (<expand the city node here and returning a list>))

(defun goal-test (city)
    (<judge using your h(n) function>))
```

Is this the form you want?
And you probably don't need other data structures, since all you need is to pass the arguments in the recursion.